# Anime where river water is contaminated by the carcass of a monster

Tags: story-identification, anime

In the anime the main character goes to an inn/restaurant along with his companions. While eating, he observes that the water is poisonous, which people are not aware of. When the main character investigates the water source (river) he finds it was because of the carcass of a monster left in the river.

Also MC tries to sell potions to the merchant. He sells potions to merchant and tells him he will bring more potions next day. But the merchant tries to kill the mc for profits and fails.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  Do you recall the names of any characters or places?

Answer (score 12):

I think you're looking for *Redo of Healer ([Kaifuku Jutsushi no Yarinaoshi](https://anidb.net/anime/15277)*)

The two scenes you're describing are in episode 3.

[image: guy with one red eye and one glowing green eye: "I suspect that the water source for this town has been contaminated by monster carcasses."]

[image: Box of vials. "How does one gold piece per dose sound?"]

Comment: The answer originally had a warning about the anime being NSFW (which can also be gained from the linked page); OP probably knows this already, but other readers might want to know.